# svg text translating and moving are not correct

Tags: svg, translate

It's my part of code to roate each text.

```
         .selectAll("text")
           .attr("y", 0)
           .attr("x", 9)
           .attr("dy", ".35em")
           .style("text-anchor", "start")
           .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "rotate(90)";
           })
```

It seems works but I don't know why

```
.attr("y", 0)
```

is move to left and right and

```
.attr("x", 9)
```

is move to up and down.

And why is text set as center with this code, not without .attr("y", 0) this line.

Comment: The transform rotates the local co-ordinate system. Why is that unxpected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have rotated the text by 90 degrees.  So now, if you move the text to the "right" by increasing the X coordinate, it will actually move downwards (because of the 90 degree rotation)